# Moving to AWS::Serverless from AWS::Lambda for changing deployment preference of lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sam

Currently we are using AWS::Lambda:Function in yaml file for cloudformation for our service. I have to change deployment preference for the lambdas present in our service. But there seems to be no key in AWS::Lambda:Function for doing that. So I was thinking to move to serverless stack setup. Is there any other alternative(except for using AWS code deploy)? What are the changes that needs to be done for this and what should I keep in mind before doing this?

Comment: AWS::Serverless:Function maps its fields to corresponding AWS::Lambda::Function fields. But there seems to be no such fields for deployment preference in AWS::Lambda::Function

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the workings of the deployment preferences you'll find that it [comes built-in with CodeDeploy to provide gradual Lambda deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/automating-updates-to-serverless-apps.html). The serverless framework is taking care of things for you that you'll have to do yourself if you want to not use it.

Comment: But I don't think we are using code deploy to deploy our service. We are using Sam for this purpose.